# Facebook payment platform 64bit order_id on 32bit server

Tags: php, facebook, callback, 32bit-64bit, payment

I'm currently running into a massive wall due to a problem i cannot seem to solve.

The problem is that, when you issue a payment through the Facebook payment platform (facebook javascript sdk), it sends data to your callback page, which should handle the payment on the background.

This all works decent, but there is 1 problem: The order ID that facebook uses is a 64bit ID, and my server is a 32bits server, thus it loses precision on the ID when it gets saved to a variable in the callback page. This ultimately results in not being able to get a proper order_ID in the end, because it cannot save the ID.

The issue has been described on several pages on this forum, for example:

[facebook credit callback, order_id changes format changes after moving to a new server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222942/facebook-credit-callback-order-id-changes-format-changes-after-moving-to-a-new)

and

[PHP: Converting a 64bit integer to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856549/php-converting-a-64bit-integer-to-string)

Yet, on both pages there is no solution to the problem, and i cannot seem to fix this myself.
I have tried to convert the json data that facebook sends to my callback page into string data instead of an array with integers (this happens in the basic code provided by facebook), but i just cannot get this to work.

Seeing that others have overcome this problem (without having to migrate everything to a 64bits server), i am wondering how.

Is anyone able to shine a light on this subject?

Edit:
I have tried converting to string, the standard facebook code that gets called to decode the json data (code provided by facebook):

```
$request = parse_signed_request($_POST['signed_request'], $app_secret);
```

This calls the function parse_signed_request, which does:

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

$sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);

$data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }
  return $data;
}
```

This function decodes the encrypted json data from facebook (using the app secret) and should decode the json data to a PHP array.

That function uses the following function (the exact:

```
function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

Now, the above code results in the order ID not being saved properly, and it loses its precision, resulting in an id like: 4.8567130814993E+14

I have tried to use the following function to somehow decode the json data into a string (so the 64bit integer ID does not lose its precision), but to no avail:

```
  function largeint($rawjson) {
    $rawjson = substr($rawjson, 1, -1);
    $rawjson = explode(',' , $rawjson);
    array_walk($rawjson, 'strfun');
    $rawjson = implode(',', $rawjson);
    $rawjson = '{' . $rawjson . '}';
    $json = json_decode($rawjson);
    return $json;
  }


function strfun(&$entry, $key) {
    $data = explode(':', $entry);
    if (FALSE === strpos($data[1], '"')) {
    $data[1] = '"' . $data[1] . '"';
    $entry = implode(':', $data);
    }
}
```

Edit (Eugenes answer):

If i were to try modifying the JSON data before i use json_decode to make it a php variable, i should be using the preg_replace function?
Below is an example of the initial JSON data that gets sent to the callback page to initiate the payment process.
Here you can already see what the problem is (this is after using json_decode, the id and other data lose their precision). The ID's are modified to not reflect any real data.
If you compare the buyer ID on the top and user id on the bottom, you can see precision is lost.

```
Array
(
[algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
[credits] => Array
    (
        [buyer] => 1.0055555551318E+14
        [receiver] => 1.0055555551318E+14
        [order_id] => 5.2555555501665E+14
        [order_info] => {"item_id":"77"}
        [test_mode] => 1
    )

[expires] => 1358456400
[issued_at] => 1358452270
[oauth_token] => AAAH4s2ZCCEMkBAPiGSNsmj98HNdTandalotmoredata
[user] => Array
    (
        [country] => nl
        [locale] => nl_NL
        [age] => Array
            (
                [min] => 21
            )

    )

[user_id] => 100555555513181
)
```

Edit #3:

I have tried the following to make all the integers in the JSON data seen as strings, but that results in an error from the facebook platform. It does however change the integers to a string, so i do not lose precision (too bad nothing else works now xD)

```
preg_replace('/([^\\\])":([0-9]{10,})(,|})/', '$1":"$2"$3', $a)
```

Comment: Yes, you need to use a string. Show us what you've tried that hasn't worked - post some code.

Comment: I have posted a lot of information in response to your comment and Eugene's comment. I have tried several things, but again, without success. I have also mailed my hosting provider about the possibility of an upgrade of the system to 64bits (or php 5.4).

Comment: So because you're altering the JSON object, your HMAC hash signature won't match. You will probably have to bypass that security feature as an additional sacrifice of the strategy. EG: You'll have to tinker with the library and bypass that hash signature check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of PHP are you running?

If you are running a version of PHP that supports the JSON "JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING" option, that may be your answer. You may have to modify their library wherever json_decode is being used to add that option. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

If your PHP version does not support JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING, then your options are limited to:

The hacky option: Do some kind of regex operation on the JSON string as it comes back from the FB API and wrap that big ints in double-quotes, so that they decode as a string and not a big int.

The ideal option: Bite the bullet and migrate to a 64 bit environment. It will save you from a lot of headaches in the long run.

Comment: The current version of PHP im using is 5.2.17. I have tried to use the JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING argument in json_decode, but the result is empty (therefor i am guessing it doesnt work). I did this by changing the code into: $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

Comment: I am pretty sure that 5.2 is not going to support that feature. I think you need to be on 5.4 for it work, actually.

Comment: Is there a way to get this working with php 5.2? I don't really have the option of upgrading php or the server at this moment. I assume people have gotten this to work with some workaround on a 32bits installation. Isn't it possible to clone the JSON result and grab the data from that result, while leaving the original intact? Or would the clone automatically be converted to 32bits already?

Comment: The only way you'll get around it on a 32 bit system in PHP 5.2 is by messing with the JSON object to make it unserialize as a string and not as an int - and that breeds other problems as you've encountered and is generally not what I consider a good practice. You're between a rock and a hard place on this one... appeal to the powers that be to either upgrade the server or upgrade the php install.

Comment: I have finally managed to work around the issue. My hosting provider only gave me the option to upgrade to php 5.3, which would only partially solve the issue. Therefor, i have just cloned the signed request and worked with that order id (using preg_replace in order to get the string data from order id) in my database. The original signed request is therefor untouched and thus matches the hash. It finally seems to work. In the long run however, i will be checking my options for a 64bits server installation. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Glad you found th solution. I you don't mind "accept" my answer if that's the solution you went with :)